# CSS: top bar alinhada

Tags: html, css

Preciso que o `h6` "BI" fique ao lado do meu `span` de menu, mas com um espaçamento considerável. Tentei fazer com `div` e `li`, mas de todas as formas, a escrita "BI" acaba abaixo do `span`.

[image: Exemplo de como está agora]

```css
.topnav {
  background-color: #111;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#spanOpen {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

#bi {
  color: #f1f1f1;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div id="topBar" class="topnav">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <span id="spanOpen" v-on:click="openMenu">&#9776;</span>
      <h5 id="bi"> BI</h5>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coloque na #Bi:

```
display:inline-block;
margin-left: 20px; //margi de acordo com o que desejar
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/atjLfhpg/

Comment: Resolvido, muito obrigada!